Error when creating a record in a table with a foreign key
I have these two tables in my mysql database:
CREATE TABLE `purchases` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `supplier` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `total` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
CREATE TABLE `purchase_details` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `purchase_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `qty` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `total` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

And I create the primary keys, the auto-increments and the alien keys:
ALTER TABLE `purchases`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `supplier` (`supplier`) USING BTREE;
ALTER TABLE `purchase_details`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `product_id` (`product_id`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `purchase_id` (`purchase_id`) USING BTREE;
ALTER TABLE `purchases`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `purchase_details`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `purchase_details`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `purchase_details_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`purchase_id`) REFERENCES `purchases` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `purchase_details_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

To test them, I first created a record in purchases, because that total stores the sum of totals of the records in purchase_details that have the purchase _id of the purchases table.
In addition, in the purchase_details form, the purchase_id to which it has to be associated appears, in an input readonly.
Then, I try to create a record in purchase_details with the purchase id I created earlier and it gives me this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Cannot add or update a
child row: a foreign key constraint fails

I've read on the internet that first you have to create the record of the secondary table and then the primary, but I have to do it the other way around.

Your table is also referencing the products table? Is that constraint met?

With the form I created I can't check it, as it gives me that error. Previously, I created two records by hand using phpmyadmin.

So how for you provide the value for product ID to that form?

I use Notepad++ with html and php.
If you tell me where, I can put the code for the whole page, for you to see

I choose the product id in a select with the list of products. But that's not the problem, I've solved it.

Either post the solution in the Answer selection below, or delete the question if it's no longe relevant.

My problem had no solution. The only thing I could do was delete the foreign key in phpmyadmin and not validate the purchase id.

That's nonsense. You obviously did provide an invalid foreign key. Did you check at your backend what the actual values where, you tried to insert?

The foreign key was valid, but when it came to entering it in the second table it conflicted with the first, since the one depended on the other. The data you wanted to enter is now entered perfectly.
